# How to create an active record search across models 3 levels deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Alright, database stuff is turning out to be my rails weakpoint.

I have 3 models I am trying to search across: User, Invoice, Payment

User has_many invoices and Invoice has_many payments.

I am trying to create a search that will find all of the payments for the current_user across a given date range.

This is how I have done this so far

```
invoices = current_user.invoices
payments = invoices.inject([]) {|arr,x| arr += x.payments.where("payment_date <= ? and payment_date >= ?", '2011-02-01', '2011-01-01')}
```

This seems insane to me. I'm sure there must be a way of getting this out of the database directly without iterating through results. Any ideas? Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use something like :

```
Payments.joins(:invoice => :user).where("users.id = ? AND (payments.payment_date <= ? and payments.payment_date >= ?)", current_user.id, '2011-02-01', '2011-01-01')
```

You probably want to read the Ruby On Rails Guides about [active record query](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

**UPDATE**:

From the guide linked, a more cleaner syntax will be :

```
time_range = (Time.now.midnight - 1.month)..Time.now.midnight
Payments.joins(:invoice => :user).where(:users => {:id => current_user.id}, :payments => {:payment_date => time_range})
```

**UPDATE 2, another solution :**

In your model `User` :

```
has_many :payments, :through => :invoices
```

To perform the query :

```
time_range = (Time.now.midnight - 1.month)..Time.now.midnight
current_user.payments.where(:payment_date => time_range)
```

Comment: Nice, I used your final solution. I don't really understand joins yet so have to do some more reading (although I realise that's what the final solution is doing under the hood). Thanks.

Comment: I will suggest you to also read about [Active Record associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)